# How to find CheckBox control in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

How to add item of checkbox in datagridview(2) to datagridview(1) 
for show data in checkbox(database) on datagridview(1)

My code

```
DataTable a = tablebill();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value);
    if (checkBoxValue == true)
    {
        a.Rows.Add(row.Cells["Products"].Value);
    }
    else { }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = a;
```

Comment: According to the code snippet you have provided, the checkbox cell is in the first cell of the row. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes it is frist, I want to select checkbox for add to datagridview

http://i.imgur.com/cPPQoMD.png?1

Sorry for language. I am study in Thailand

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to add those values when a checkbox click event is triggered. If so, you could try the following..

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //This will indicate the end of the cell edit (checkbox checked)
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index &&
        e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index && 
        e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        //Handle your checkbox state change here
        DataTable a = tablebill();
        bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
        if (checkBoxValue == true)
        {
            a.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Products"].Value);
        }
        else { }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = a;
    }
}
```

PS. Remember to properly add your `dataGridView1` event handlers.